# PHP array : renumber elements when new element added

Tags: php, arrays, shift

I have a PHP array with elements:

```
$myarray = array ( "tom", "dick", "Harry" );
```

. I need to keep the array fixed in size of just 3 elements
. I need to add a new element "jerry" such that the array now looks like

```
 $myarray = array ( "jerry", "tom", "dick");
```

so in a way I am moving the elements along and the 4th one drops out, with the newest element going at the beginning. I could write all of this by hand, renumbering the elements etc etc.

I just wondered if there was a quicker way to do this though.

Many thanks!
J

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do this is to utilize [`array_pop`](http://www.php.net/array_pop) and [`array_unshift`](http://www.php.net/array_unshift):

```
# Pop the last element off the array
array_pop($myarray);

# Insert the new value
array_unshift($myarray, "jerry");
```

Or, you can use [`array_merge`](http://www.php.net/array_merge) and [`array_slice`](http://www.php.net/array_slice):

```
$myarray = array_merge(array("jerry"), array_slice($myarray, 0, 2));
```

Both of these methods reset the keys, so they will be renumbered from 0 to 2.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at [SplQueue](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/class.splqueue.php). On every addition of a new element, check whether the number of elements is higher than x and dequeue if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
$myarray = array ( "tom", "dick", "Harry" );
array_pop( $myarray ); //remove the last element
array_unshift( $myarray, "jerry" ); //prepend the new element
```